# Creating a PDF for Google Cloud Print on Android

Tags: android, printing, google-cloud-print

I'm trying to allow my users to print a simple string from their phones when they request. I've found Google Cloud Print and that seems like the way to go. However, converting this simple string to a PDF seems to be more complicated.

Are there any simple libraries or ways to throw a string into a PDF file? Or is there any easier to print a string to a printer? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

I am not an Android developer but this should do the trick: [Creating a simple document in Java using itext](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-itext/document.html)!

About Google Cloud Print I would be a bit weary of using it. In my experience it is a bit unstable and there is no support at Google at the moment (Just checked with Google Dev. Support team). We have decided to look for another way to do cloud printing because of this.

Answer (score 0):

Try droidtext library. I have used this for creating pdf and have succeeded in printing the document.